# Spark 3.1 joining two datasets in Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 datasets as below,

```
dataset1
+--------------------+----------------+
|ids                 | names          |
+--------------------+-----------------
|1236015             | aaaaa          |
|234567              | bbbbb          |
|90909090            | ccccc          |
+--------------------+-----------------

and this is schema for dataset1

root
 |-- ids: string (nullable = true)
 |-- names: string (nullable = true)


dataset2
+--------------------+
|ids                 |
+--------------------+
|1236015             |
|90909090            |
|1345677             |
+--------------------+
and this is schema for dataset
root
 |-- ids: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to remove rows from dataset1 if the ids are present in dataset2
like this

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|ids                 | names          |
+--------------------+-----------------
|234567              | bbbbb          |
|90909090            | ccccc          |
---------------------------------------
```

I tried following

```
 dataset1.join(dataset2,col("ids").notEqual(col("ids")), "semi");
```

...but it returns all rows from dataset1. What could be the issue?

Comment: `col("ids").notEqual(col("ids"))` is going to refer to the same column, so that doesn't seem right

Answer (score 1):

As [Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#anti-join) says:

> **Anti Join** 
> An anti join returns values from the left relation that has
> no match with the right. It is also referred to as a left anti join.

So in your case it is probably

```
dataset1.join(dataset2,dataset1.col("ids").equalTo(dataset2.col("ids")), "leftanti");
```